# Ho to generate month and year dynamicaly based on start and date we provided in ssrs sharepoint

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sharepoint-2013

[image: preview]

if I provide date like did it has dynamically generate like
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as your column header:

=format(Fields!Date.Value, "MMM")& "-" & format(fields!Date.Value, "yy")